# Overshoot/undershoot issues in load current wave form of a MOSFET

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, powermosfet

We have designed hardware circuit which validates voltage regulator maximum output current.
So we designed op-amp circuitry to control gate drive of the Power MOSFET and it will work in active region and pass the regulator output current through MOSFET. Here the Mosfet is our Load.

Issue: In our design we are capturing the output current wave form it shows the overshoot and undershoot in it. I suspect MOSFET input capacitance causing this issue. We have RC circuit for compensation to this but I need to understand this issue clearly and what are the possibilities causing the issue. Kindly help me on this

Attached is our op-amp circuit schematic and MOSFET design.[image]
[image]

Sorry for delaying to upload the output wave form where I can see overshoot, undershoot in it (circled in yellow)

[image]

Comment: Surely the waveform itself and details about how you measure it and attach the probe is not important enough to mention it here.

Comment: The overshoot could be from the measurement, supply frequencies

Comment: It is not clear what out is, and what in is. 4 different nets that share names?

Comment: RAIL1_GD1 net is driving MOSFET gate voltage by op-amp in first circuit.
RAIL1_IS1_H/_L net used to sense the load current in volts and given to error amplifier in first circuit back.

Comment: DON’T PARALLEL MOSFETS WITHOUT INDIVIDUAL GATE RESISTORS! *caps lock off* Also, show layout and decoupling. Where are your pull-down resistors?

Comment: @Winny, Could you please let me know how to calculate the Gate series resistor value for my design??

Comment: Start with 10 ohm. Perhaps you can calculate it, butI end up finding a correct value experimentally in the end. 10 ohm is a good starting point in most cases.

Comment: Hi Winny thanks, I will validate and let you know the result